# what does ''live through one's child'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

The sentence is this

> if you know a better way for me to live through my son, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: It sounds like living *[vicariously](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vicarious)*.

Comment: I think it may refer to living through the death of a son, that is accept their death and go on.

Comment: It Needs More Context. Why? Because there might be more than one interpretation.  Where did you read this sentence? What was written before and after? Please include a link, if there is one, to the original text.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner - To this American English speaker, it doesn't sound anything like living through the death of a son.  "living through the death of X" is not at all like "living through X".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual meaning, as [Mick suggests](//ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105929/what-does-live-through-ones-child-mean#comment210897_105929), is to live the life one wants to have through close involvement in someone else’s life. It’s commonly used to talk about parents who had ambitions that didn't go as far as they wanted, and are pushing their children to achieve similar things so the parents can feel accomplished. It can also be used for any other case where one person’s desires are satisfied by making someone else achieve them.

Comment: But why say "if you know a **better way** for me to live...."? The phrase "to live through someone" is usually said by others, a reproach, a criticism, not by the parent or parents themselves.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It could be sarcastic or self-deprecating.

Comment: yes, it's sarcastic and  was in a comedy series. thanks a lot.

Comment: @MasihK why wouldn't you say this in your question?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: sorry, that was my bad. however, before knowing the meaning I wasn't able to decide whether it was sarcastic.

Comment: @MasihK so it's only because I queried the meaning of "a better way" that Nathan came up with sarcasm, and then it made sense to you. But it didn't make sense to me until you said you heard it on a comedy series. Context, people, context! Why do so many non native speakers just write a single line and expects users to understand the nuances, and shades of meaning. It's nigh on impossible. This rant is also for the benefit of  anyone who happens to drop by.